# Windows Phone 8 PhoneGap HTML Select dropdown fires 2 Times

Tags: html, cordova, dojo

I have a PhoneGap WP8 App!
In the index.html I have a HTML Select

```
    <div id="loginInputDiv">
        <input id="inputServer" type="text" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TextBox" placeholder="Servers" value="">
        <div class="serverHistory">
            <select id="lastServer" onmousedown="selectURL()"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So if I click the select I want to get **ONE** query!

```
function readSavedServers() {//read saved URLs from local store and put them in dropdown list
    return;
    var arrayInputServer = null;

    try
    {
        arrayInputServer = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("arrayInputServer"));
    }
    catch(e) { }

    if (arrayInputServer == null) {
        return;
    }

    document.getElementById('lastServer').options = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayInputServer.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('lastServer').options[i] = new Option(arrayInputServer[i], arrayInputServer[i], false, false);
    }
}
```

In this Code I want to make for every string in the Array a new Option in the select
(this code runs at startup)

```
function selectURL() { //put selected URL from dropdown list in server url input box
    document.getElementById("inputServer").value = document.getElementById('lastServer').options[document.getElementById('lastServer').selectedIndex].value;
}
```

And this is the selectURL() function that get fires if I click the select

So everything is workling fine but i got TWO query's if I click the select

I'm using an Windows Phone 8 with the Windows Phone IE 10

Comment: Why are you not using onChange,  its what is commonly used for Select box's

Comment: Are you testing on the emulator? I get the same issue on dojo(1.9.3) android(4.4) phonegap(3.5) emulator. It works fine on the real device though at least for the moment. I have not yet tested on windows 8.